# How to bind the jquery grid using KO in jquery?

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js

How to bind the [jquery grid](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/34246941/Grid) to a list in KO and also automatically have the cell values updated when the underlying KO object values update?

Comment: i just set a jsondata/array to the jquery grid.

Comment: Then show some code. Or better yet, set up a JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Here is the sample  http://jsfiddle.net/bala_krishnan/dWFTZ/8/

Answer (score 0):

That's not how I would ordinarily do KO bindings, but all you have to do to make it work that way is insert the following line after you make your change:

$("#tasks-table").grid('refresh');

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your response, if i do like this means,grid starts re-render all the rows, this is highly expensive because i have more then 100 rows. i am looking for a solution which will update the corresponding cell only, not the entire grid.